# How would you show $\mathbb{Q}=\langle \frac{1}{n!}: n\in \mathbb{N} \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

The containment of one side is obvious, but I can't see how to show $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq\langle \frac{1}{n!}: n\in \mathbb{N} \rangle$, and would prefer an answer that shows the set containment via algebraic techniques.

I am mean how to show that every rational number can be written as a finite sum of the reciprocals of factorials (or their negatives)?

That is, I am considering the rationals as an additive group and $\langle \cdot \rangle$ means the subgroup generated by the set.

Comment: Is this a question about rings, groups, $\Bbb Z$-modules, $\Bbb Q$ vector spaces?

Comment: @user2520938 Sorry if this isn't tagged correctly. I couldn't decide where this would be an appropriate question to ask. I just wanted to know how would I show these two sets equal, that's all.

Comment: If $n>b$ then $n!=b\times m$ so $\frac ab=\frac {am}{n!}$.

Comment: @user264885 see my answer to hopefully understand the relevance of my comment.

Comment: Note:  I am assuming that you meant "show that every rational number can be written as a finite sum of the reciprocals of factorials (or their negatives)"  .  If you meant something else, you should clarify.

Comment: @lulu Yes your interpretation is correct and that is the question I was asking.

Comment: So, then my argument shows this.  It doesn't show uniqueness, but of course there isn't any trivial sort of uniqueness, as $\frac 46 = 4\times \frac 1{3!}=\frac 1{2!}+\frac 1{3!}$ for example. Maybe it's like [Egyptian fractions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html) in that the greedy algorithm generates a viable expression and you can call that the representation.  Not sure if that works out well.

Comment: Say you want $\frac{a}{b},\ a,b > 0$, then $\frac{a}{b}= a(b-1)! \cdot \frac{1}{b!}$.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the help.

Comment: You could avoid all of these problems about not knowing whether you were talking about groups or rings by writing $({\mathbb Q},+)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic that $\Bbb Q$ is generated, as a group, by the set
$$
\left\{\frac1{p^k}\text{ such that $p$ is prime and $k>0$}\right\}
$$
(one can make this set of generators smaller, but that is irrelevant here). Then it is enough to show that each $1/p^k$ can be obtained from the $1/n!$, but then it is enough to notice that
$$
\frac1{p^k}=(p^k-1)!\frac1{(p^k)!}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The generated subgroup also contains any finite sum of the same element $k$ times since 
$$\frac{k}{n!} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{n!} + \ldots \frac{1}{n!}}_{k \text{ times}}.$$

EDIT: I hope I understood the question correctly. If not, please leave a comment.